# Aurelia repeater for an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, aurelia, repeater

In an Aurelia JS file I have:

```
export class Tasks {
  constructor() {
    this.categories = [];
    class category {
      node = null;
      tasks = [];
    };
...
}
```

'categories' becomes an array of x number of category objects.
category.node retains one object.
category.tasks contains an array of objects.

In the HTML, I can successfully:

```
<div repeat.for="category of categories">
  ${category.node.title}
</div>
```

But I cannot iterate through tasks underneath it (simplified, below).

```
<div repeat.for="category of categories">
  ${category.node.title} <br />
  <div repeat.for="task of category.tasks[0]">  // this line here
    Title: ${task.title}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I did same myself and it works as expected. Can you share your full code? Including the actual data.

Comment: Why your tasks array is actually "array of array of tasks"??

Comment: _I cannot iterate_ - why not, does it throw an error message?

Comment: Try: <div repeat.for="task of category.tasks[0][0]">, looks like your tasks array is 2-dimensional, so ${task.title} is undefined in your code.